# Error: unknown escape sequence '\^' in Itanium

Tags: c++, regex

I am using the following regular expression in Window C++ code:

```
regex expressionD("\^_+\\d+_\\d+_\\d+_.*\$");
```

But it gives me an error. So I replace single backslash with double backslash which work fine in Solaris, but creates problem in Itanium.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you use `^` as symbol or as beginning of string?

Comment: Please put a version of the actual RE you want **without** trying to escape it in a string literal. As it is now, it is unclear what, if anything, in your posted code you're intentionally escaping as C-string data vs. intended RE-escaped backslash.

Comment: Unfortunately VC++ doesn't support it yet, but the proper solution is `R"(\^_+\\d+_\\d+_\\d+_.*\$)"`

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the backslash again

```
regex expressionD("\\^+\\d+\\d+\\d+.*\\$");
```

Comment: as I mentioned above I already replaced the single backslash with double backslash which work fine in solaris, but create problem in itanium. Please read my approaches above.

Comment: +1, this is the correct solution. There is no `\^` escape sequence in this string, unlike in your example. The first `\` escapes the second `\`, so the `^` is unescaped.

Comment: as I mentioned above , replaced single backslash with double backslash and new string will be:
regex expressionD("\\^_+\\d+_\\d+_\\d+_.*\\$");
it work fine in solaris , but create problem in itanium

Comment: Hi Experts
 
The problem has been solved by using the following syntax:-
regex expressionD("^_+\\d+_\\d+_\\d+_.*$");
Anyway thanks to all for their support.

Comment: @vikasBhutani you never told us that you didnt want to match the carat and dollar literally.

Comment: no its not like that...I tested that it is working for carat and dollor too that was found in the initial and end of regular expression.